# How can I directly access my web application deployed in AWS tomcat using domain address?

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I have deployed my Angular2 web application in AWS tomcat server which runs in 8080 port.  I have my spring boot backend application deployed in the same tomcat server.

Already mapped my public address with my registered domain in Godaddy.

Now I can access my application appln by **http://example.com:8080/my_client**

I want to access it directly by **http://example.com**. dnt want to see 8080 port and appln name in the url.

Already tried with apache proxy config. However not able to get the expected one.

Comment: Run this iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options

1) change tomcat port from 8080 to 80 ( not recommended ).

nano tomcat_dir/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
connectionTimeout="20000"
redirectPort="8443" />
```

2) use apache virtual host config.

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off
  ServerName example.com
  ProxyPass http://example.com http://localhost:8080/example
  ProxyPassReverse http://example.com http://localhost:8080/example
</VirtualHost>
```